# How do I ensure that my AngularJS elements have a scope/injector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

<strike>I have a small AngularJS app providing functionality to a larger non-angular application. I need to access the injector in the inner (AngularJS) app to get at the services it provides, but I find that in certain situations, the DOM elements have no scope or injector attached. This is especially noticeable if the website has 2 angular apps (the only way I can reliably recreate the problem, 'though as I said, I am only using 1 angular app inside a larger application).  An example of the problem can be found [here - http://jsfiddle.net/n3y8c96a/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/n3y8c96a/1/).</strike>

A colleague updated JQuery to `2.1.1` from `1.11.1` and now my element has no scope connected to it. You can see it in [this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n3y8c96a/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/n3y8c96a/8/).  If you change the jquery version to a 1.x version, it works and can show the scope.

This should work with any JQuery version.  Is there a way to either ensure that the proper scope is automatically "attached" to the element or to manually do so?

Comment: In your jsfiddle, #app2 doesn't have a scope/injector cause it haven't been bootstraped yet. Angular will bootstrap the first element with `ng-app` on DOM loaded.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue you described in your jsfiddle. Do you also see the issue in the jsfiddle?

Comment: @runTarm You are right.  I cannot reliably recreate the issue as well. I will remove the jsfiddle from the original post.  Does anybody know why angular would not add a scope or injector to an element?  I don't know what the scope() function on an angular.element actually does...

Comment: Replace the last part with this instead: `'scope for app: ' + angular.element(document.getElementById("app")).scope()));`. The `app` variable is referencing the old `element-directive` DOM element, which is destroyed after bootstrap when the directive is executed and the DOM element replaced with the directive's template. Haven't looked into why it works with 1.11.1 though.

Comment: That's weird.  Still not working in my app, though.  I still get scope undefined if I use jQuery 2.x